# Counting Single Post Views With Php and Mysqli Not Working Accurately With This Code

Tags: php, mysqli

Am Programming With My Android Phone (Palapa Web Server)

I want to get accurate counts of post views each time single post is loaded,but I have tried with the following code and when I load or view a post with the code it counts but in the database it add extra one on the accurate counts.

(E.g the last count is "20" but when i reload the post it will show "22" in the database).

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
// Set queries 
$q ="SELECT views FROM chaly_post WHERE id ='$post_id' LIMIT 1"; 
$r=@mysqli_query($connect,$q);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    echo $views=$row['views'];
}

if ($views){
    $f ="UPDATE chaly_post SET views=(views+1) WHERE id=$post_id";
    $s = @mysqli_query($connect,$f);
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing gets better answers than starting with "*geeks in the house*"

Comment: [*"Please! geeks in the house?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36089723/1) - Freak, yes. Geek, no.

Comment: How are you setting `$post_id`?

Comment: *OP just undid your beautiful edit there Sam* @JayBlanchard Edit: refixed.

Comment: *Undid the undid Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Please accept my mistakes this is my first question here.. Please

Comment: $post_id=(int)$_GET['id']; @ jay

Comment: Thanks for the editing @Mr. Jay

Comment: Any Answer please?

Comment: Count in database 20. Run script, script echo 20, script update database to 21. Reload, script echo 21, script update database to 22.

Comment: "Any Answer please?"; there are 13minutes separating this comment and your question being posted... Leave people some time to answer your question, move on something else and come back later.

Comment: Ya its add extra 1 to the value in the database, if the accurate value should be 9 if you echo the database column it will show 11 @frz3993

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$f ="UPDATE chaly_post SET views=(views+1) WHERE id=$post_id";
```

To

```
$views = $views + 1;
$f ="UPDATE chaly_post SET views='{$views}' WHERE id=$post_id";
```

Remove the @ here:

```
$r=@mysqli_query($connect,$q);
```

And here:

```
$s = @mysqli_query($connect,$f);
```

Comment: I did so, but it still add extra one after the accurate value.

Comment: I thought the problem is from the database because, if I run the script and echo the $view it shows accurate value but when storing in the database it will add extra one..

Comment: Remove your while, you don't need it if its just 1 single row you're getting. Try using "var_dump" in "$views" before the "$views = $views + 1;" then, try again to var_dump the same var. Check what shows, and after that, do the update if the var had "20" and then "21".

Comment: Thanks for your concern and help

Comment: Help me with more explanation on "var_dump" thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. Just, before the var $views, use: var_dump($views); then after the $views = $views + 1; use it again. You should have "20" then "21" for example, if you're gettin' "20" and then "22" there's a problem. If that var is ok, then your update should works. Also, you could try another way to do that. Its very simple, everytime someone visits your site, you can just INSERT a row in a table, with the POST_ID and with the IP (if you want to) then, you can simple count how much rows with the POST_ID are, and its done (just another way to do it).